# Como cortar um sufixo de uma expressão no bash (egrep/sed/etc)

Tags: regex, bash

Eu estou fazendo um script que trabalha com diretorios que tem sufixos definidos e separados por ".", por exemplo "pasta.teste.git" ou "coisas.var" e gostaria de pegar como variável apenas o prefixo eliminando a ultima parte (por ex o nome "pasta.teste" ou "coisas").

Eu tentei com o cut e o grep mas não consegui pegar de trás pra frente. N~]ao consegui eliminar a ultima ocorrencia após o ".".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa usar nenhuma ferramenta extra para isso, pois o próprio `bash` é capaz de separar estas palavras. Atribua o nome de arquivo a uma variável e utilize o modificador `%`:

```
nome_de_arquivo_completo="pasta.teste.git"
nome_de_arquivo_sem_extensao="${nome_de_arquivo_completo%.*}"
echo "${nome_de_arquivo_sem_extensao}"
```

Ou, num exemplo prático com vários arquivos no diretório atual:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *; do
    echo "${filename%.*}"
done
```

O que acontece é que o modificador `%` remove do final de uma variável o padrão especificado logo em seguida (`.*`, no caso).

Comment: Eu tinha vindo aqui exatamente pra responder minha própria pergunta rsrs... Cara, obrigado!

Comment: De nada, disponha.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente nestas situações é util ficarmos com prefixo e com o sufixo.
Já agora usando outra abordagem diferente:

```
ls -d *.*/ |                      ## get directorias contendo "."
sed -r 's!(.*)\.(.*)/!\1\n\2!' |  ## separar prefixo suf.
while read p && read e            ## para cada par (prefixo, suf)
do  
   echo "Prefixo: $p" "suf: $e"   ## processar em função do prefixo, suf
done
```

Exemplo de processamento: arrumar as directorias em função do suf -- substituir o "echo" por:

```
mkdir -p $e
mv "$p.$e" $e/$p
```

Comment: Cara, muito bom! Eu tentei fazer em regex mas não consegui, vc matou a pau! Obrigado!

Comment: Everton, obrigado, fico contente; ainda assim parece-me que a resposta do @FernandoSilveira responde mais directamente à questão formulada.